# Are IgE antibodies capable of binding water molecules?

Tags: cell-biology

I learned in med school, that they are too small to trigger the IgE reaction that causes the release of histamine. However, I came across reports of this condition;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquagenic_urticaria

Some people with this cannot drink plain water without experiencing symptoms in their mouths and throats. In some cases, they report anaphylaxis if they drink a sip of water. The drug 'Xolair' blocks IgE and is effective in people with this condition.

But, I thought the water molecule is too small to bind to IgE antibodies? At least, that was what I learned in med school. Now I'm kind of confused. Aren't IgE antibodies literally dissolved in/surrounded by water on a constant basis? Wouldn't the water in the liquid these cells are always in be triggering a 24/7 reaction in their skin and their throats? Not just when they drink some water or take a shower. The epidermis is just dead cells, the mast cells in the skin have to be submerged in a mostly water medium to survive.

These people rely on milk and orange juice to drink, as it does not elicit the internal allergy reactions.

https://rarediseases.info.nih.gov/diseases/10901/aquagenic-urticaria

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3276800/

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32940373/

https://www.businessinsider.com/toddler-allergic-to-water-aquagenic-urticaria-2018-2?op=1

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. For the reasons you mention it seems clear that this can not be a reaction to water molecules. (However, note that anything in aqueous solution will have many interactions with water molecules.) Please [edit] your post to include more reliable background information — I suggest you look at other sources in addition to Wikipedia (it's a fine place to start, but the quality of the information can be highly variable). Please see the [tour] and  [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively for details of what is expected in posts on this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### It is as you suggest: IgE antibodies are incapable of binding to water.

The immunogenicity of water is not explainable that simply. It is also important to know that it is a variant of physical urticaria, which presents the same symptoms but via different provocation, such as pressure, cold, heat, or exercise and sweating (cholinergic urticaria). There is some discussion on the topic [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3276800/).

Some competing explanations in the links you provide are:

- water reacts with something on the body, and the product of the reaction is immunogenic, or water solubilizes a surface antigen that penetrates the skin, and
- contaminants or impurities in the water elicit the immune response.

First, I will offer my amateur thoughts on the matter, and then provide you with transcripts of what doctors who have had experience with treating this have come to understand. Do note that this is still an incompletely understood (rare) disease and that there exists no definitive mechanistic understanding, though histopathological examination has been performed, and it does indeed seem like the presence of water induces an immune reaction. It also seems immunologic due to the fact that patients respond well to antihistamines and related treatments that suppress the immune system.

As you can guess, this is a very rare disorder and it is difficult to rule out things such as an uncommon reaction to (perhaps) improperly cleaned or cleared water. However, some studies have been done to rule out impurities in water by the use of a water provocation test, or "water challenge test", where source of the water has been shown to not matter, thereby likely ruling out the impurities hypothesis. [Patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3276800/) also have similar responses to rain, tap water and swimming pool water. It too may be that the preparation, processing or chemistry of milk or orange juice renders an aqueous medium as incapable of eliciting a reaction on the skin, perhaps due to the presence of molecules or simply by virtue of things like pH being different than that of water. Reportedly, pH and temperature [do need seem to play a role](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ccr3.2880). It is also possible, though unlikely, that the immune response to water is *psychogenic*, and seems to occur more predominantly in females around puberty, and has been [anecdotally reported](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/ccr3.2880) to co-occur with some diseases like Bernard-Soulier syndrome, polymorphic light eruption, familial lactose intolerance and papillary carcinoma of the thyroid.

Anyway, I doubt anyone here at this SE can do a better job than the summaries I have here below.

A discussion of the cases and literature from 2011 can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3276800/):

> The pathogenesis of AU is not fully known; however, several mechanisms have been proposed. *Interaction with water with a component in or on the stratum corneum or sebum, generating a toxic compound, has been suggested. Absorption of this substance would exert an effect of perifollicular mast cell degranulation with release of histamine.* A study by Sibbald et al. demonstrated that **complete removal of the stratum corneum appeared to worsen the reaction**, rather than prevent urticaria. These authors also demonstrated that **pretreatment with organic solvents enhances wheal formation in contact with water**. They suggested that **enhancement of the ability of water to penetrate the stratum corneum increases wheal formation**. Czarnetzki et al. hypothesized the existence of a water-soluble antigen at the epidermal layer. The antigen diffuses into the dermis by water and then causes release of histamine from mast cells. Tkach hypothesized that hypotonic water sources could lead to osmotic pressure changes, resulting in indirect provocation of urticaria. **Others have recently stated that 5% saline was more effective than distilled water for eliciting the wheal-and-flare reaction**. They hypothesized that the **salt concentration and/or water osmolarity may influence the pathogenic process of AU, possibly by enhancing solubilization and penetration of a hypothetical epidermal antigen**, in the same way as has been postulated for enhancement of organic solvents. Another proposed chemical mediator in AU is acetylcholine because of the ability of the acetylcholine antagonist scopolamine to suppress wheal formation when applied to the skin before water contact. However, *another study failed to reproduce this finding when pretreatment with atropine did not result in suppression of subsequent wheal formation*. Methacholine injection testing is negative in patients with AU; however, it is often positive in cholinergic urticaria. Serum histamine levels are variable from patient to patient. Antihistamines have been used to treat AU; however, the therapeutic effect and prognosis vary. In some cases, complete control of symptoms with antihistamine has been reported, whereas in other cases, there is a failure to adequately control symptoms. Refractory cases have been treated with ultraviolet (UV) radiation (both psoralen plus UVA therapy and UVB), either alone or in combination with antihistamines. It is hypothesized that the **effect of ultraviolet therapy is mediated by thickening of the epidermis, which may prevent water penetration, interaction with dendritic cells, and immunosuppression or a decreased mast cell response**. Barrier methods involving application of oil-in-water emulsion creams on the skin for water protection are effective. AU responds to stanazolol treatment in human immunodeficiency virus-positive patients.

Another discussion, from a [paper from 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5438944/):

> **Many of these histopathologic findings are the same as those of acute
> urticaria, in which interstitial dermal edema, dilated venules,
> endothelial swelling, and sparse infiltration of inflammatory cells
> have been described. Mast cells are concentrated around the blood
> vessels of normal dermis, with one to three cells per cross-sectional
> vessel profile, but in this patient there were slightly increased
> numbers of mast cells around blood vessels.**
>
> Antihistamines are the first line treatment for aquagenic urticaria.
> In recalcitrant cases, the dose can be increased by as much as
> four-fold the conventional dose. Phototherapy and barrier cream are
> alternative or additional treatments if antihistamines fail to prevent
> recurrence. The efficacy of phototherapy is related to its induction
> of both immunosuppression, including a decreased mast cell response,
> and epidermal thickening, which disturbs the penetration of water and
> thus also inhibits mast cell stimulation. Barrier cream prevents
> the penetration of water into the dermis. However, the various
> emollients and water-resistant creams investigated have not yielded
> conspicuous success, except in a few cases in which a
> petrolatum-containing ointment was applied before water exposure.
> Anticholinergics such as scopolamine may also offer relief. Most of
> the patients were successfully controlled with antihistamines,
> although some of them changed treatment modalities because of
> drowsiness.